# Azure Data Explorer, Kusto: Replace regex question

Tags: regex, azure-data-explorer, kql

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/replace-regex-function) we can use replace_regex() to make complex replace in strings.
I want to change first letter in json-field key to lower case. This is how my code looks like

```
let example = @'{"Id":"00000","Categories":[{"Position":208, "CategoryId":"XXX"}]}';
print(replace("\"([^\"]+?)\"\\s*:", @'\l\1', example))
```

It does not work because I cant' do anything meaningful in replacement pattern.

```
replace("\"([^\"]+?)\"\\s*:", tolower(@'\0'), example)
```

or

```
replace("\"([^\"]+?)\"\\s*:", (@'tolower(\0)'), example)
```

don't work either.

> rewrite: The replacement regex for any match made by matchingRegex.
> Use \0 to refer to the whole match, \1 for the first capture group, \2
> and so on for subsequent capture groups.

Can we use matches (\0, \1, \2) more than just concatenating as in example?

Answer (score 3):

This is not quite possible to do with regex.
A partial solution (that changes 1st-level keys) can be done with the following query:

```
let example = parse_json(@'{"Id":"00000","Categories":[{"Position":208, "CategoryId":"XXX"}]}');
print x=example
| mv-apply kvp = example on
(
    mv-expand kind=array kvp
    | project k = tolower(kvp[0]), v=kvp[1]
    | summarize x=make_bag(pack(k, v))
)
```

Comment: Thank you! But if we consider not only the keys could we can't do something complicated with regex replacement, can we?

Comment: If you need both keys/values- you can call tolower() on the whole string (it shouldn't affect json-parsing). Regex replacement doesn't allow running labmda transformation for strings being replaced (in a sense, that's what you wanted: apply tolower() over \1)